# Memory usage is much larger when running in tests (NUnit) than in normal mode (WinForms app)

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, rider, zedgraph

When I use a ZedGraph control in NUnit/MSTest test method the memory usage is much larger (over 8GB for control instance) than in WinForms application.
I use Windows 10 Pro, Rider 2021.1.3, C# 7.1, .NET Framework 4.6, AMD Ryzen 7

When use with WinForms, the main process uses 10 MB of RAM:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        var before= System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64; 
        Console.WriteLine("before: " + before/1024/1024); // gives: 13.2
        var zg1 = new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl();
        var after = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
        Console.WriteLine("after: " + after/1024/1024); // gives: 17.5 
    }
}
```

When use in tests, the ReSharperTestRunner64 process uses 8197,4 MB of RAM:

```
public class TestMemory
{
    [Test]
    public void testMemory()
    {
        var before = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
        Console.WriteLine("before: " + before/1024/1024); //gives: 120.6
        var zg1 = new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl();
        var after = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64;
        Console.WriteLine("after: " + after/1024/1024); //gives: 8333.5
    }
}
```

I dont understand the difference and cant reproduce the problem on the PC with Intel CPU.

Comment: I suppose that  new ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl(); is occuping that amount of memory

Comment: Bear in mind you're looking at virtual memory. `PrivateMemorySize64` may be more informative